# how to keep a clickable link behind a table in HTML?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background-image, html-table

I'm wondering if it's possible to have clickable links behind a css table.
When the images are 40px there is no way to select the link behind it.

Why i made it in a table is because every text block needs to be 248px (744/3)

CSS

```
#tabel{
    position:absolute;
}
table, td, th
{
width:744px;
height:40px;
text-align:center;
}
th
{
background-color:transparent;
color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabel">    
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th>TXT 1</th>
        <th>TXT 2</th>
        <th>TXT 3</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My goal is to have 3 clickable buttons (for an jquery image-slider with navigation) with text on top of it.

Comment: Why don't you display:none the buttons until it is time to show them?

Comment: Why don't you set your event handler on `th`?

Comment: Because that removes the text? which i want to be visible..

Comment: Sorry, was to the first one. I'm a noob... but i dont know what an event handler is?

Comment: You don't need to use tables to get your elements to be 248px wide.  Unless it is tabular data, it shouldn't be in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take the tableless approach like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t4tBt/

CSS

```
a.mybutton {
    display:block;
    width:248px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#999;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:10px;
}
a.first{
   background:url('http://www.trade-website.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/simple_blue_background-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');
}
a.second {
background:url('http://www.trade-website.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/simple_blue_background-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');
}
a.last {
background:url('http://www.trade-website.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/simple_blue_background-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabel">
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="mybutton first">First Button</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="mybutton second">Second Button</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="mybutton last">Third Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Fixed it, thnx! Though still i cant click the underlaying image which is in jquery.